# How can I browse ALL files via taskbar tree browse?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

There is a simple trick in windows that can allows us to browse all the computer via single click via the Toolbar.

How ?

This is my Current toolbar :

[image]

Right click and :

[image]

Select your Computer :

[image]

It will append this to the toolbar :

[image]

Now drag this to the left :

[image]

You will see this :

[image]

Now , at the right side drag this to the left again :

[image]

Now - when you click on the `>>` you can browse in a tree way - the whole computer.

[image]

Pretty helpful for quick navigation.

**Question**

The problem is that it doesn't show hidden folders like `AppData`  :

For example  - I do have this folder :

```
C:\Users\sff\AppData
```

But as you can see : No AppData in here :

[image]

Is there anyway (registry maybe?) that this browsing will **show** all folders ?(I don't want to change `rsha` attributes  obviously).

FYI , the display options for hidden files and system folder are all ON   , So I do see them in Explorer :

[image]

`AppData` is just a sample. Tomorrow it can be `MyHiddenfolder`.

Comment: It *might* be possible.  It does pull custom folder icons, so its doesnt appear to be just a simple directory tree.

Comment: Have you [enabled showing hidden files and folders](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7)?

Comment: @harrymc The last image in the question shows that I have.

Comment: @RoyiNamir do you want to do this with windows settings or another program is also fine?

Comment: @MyUserName I don't care. All I want is this to work ( without attrib -h *.*)

Answer (score 2):

This menu structure does not support hidden files and folders, but you can create a 2nd link to it that will work using mklink.

Open a command prompt with administrative privileges, and enter:
`mklink /j c:\Users\sff\App_Data c:\Users\sff\AppData`

A new shortcut folder will be created and it will show up in your tree. Of course if you browse to the folder, you'll see 2 AppData folders, but there's no way around it.

Comment: Any registry key that solves it?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Thank you. But today it's `AppData` , tomorrow it can be `MyHiddenFolder`. I'm not going to make dups for every folder :-)

Comment: Maybe you have to look for a different method to browse your files.

Comment: +1 for LPChip comment, Windows Explorer is not supporting to browse hidden folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have reasons to think this is not possible – except for directory junction workaround provided in the other answer.

You are focusing on Explorer toolbar functionality which is here for mainly for convenience of ordinary users. For them, showing hidden folders just makes no sense (or can be even dangerous). No wonder this wasn't made configurable. Advanced users have available plenty of other ways of navigation.

And I see you have Visual Studio open :). If you are badly missing hidden folders on that toolbar, you can [create your own toolbar (actually a **Desk Band**)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx) for this task. Also you can add possibility of pinning of your favorite files and folders which will make your navigation even more faster than with out-of-the-box toolbar.

Based on your StackOverflow profile, here you have a nice guide for [Desk Bands in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and) which includes downloadable Visual Studio solution where most of work is already done. Extending it to view directory tree should be a breeze for you.